# How to make the path to equal to other path in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, selections

I have the two paths this in illustrator, this path could be any anywhere it could be part of the complex drawing.

And I have another path which also could be anywhere. I could select both of the paths with direct selection tools.

How do I make the one length of the path equal to the other path length?

Comment: You dont illustrator is not a constraint based solver. Or do you maean have same stroke and effect

Comment: What does "equal" mean in this context? Same weight? Same length? same arc? Same color? Same anchor points? Same position? All of the above?

Comment: Picture please, I have no clue what you're talking about without one 

Comment: basically, I want the length to be equal, however, I could just duplicate the path and use that, but that requires lot of effort since two-path could be part of complex drawing.

Comment: Well, you *could* get the length of any path via the Document Info Panel. However, applying that length to another path may not be so easy, especially if the path to change is at any sort of angle - and of course, curves could never be transposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illustrator is a direct modeling tool*. It has no constraints based features like cad applications do. There is no inbuilt featureto make something same as another.

Copying is the way to go. All you really need is to stelect the segment and alt drag it into place. This is more often than not faster than defining a constraint in a cad application because there is no context switch.

You could ofcourse script this but it would still be inferior to alt dragging in terms of speed. And in scripting this you will probably find that its not entirely trivial to do this if you dont have constraints.

* Its a tradeoff indirect modeling is more demanding and disalows things that it wasnt intended to do.